# Anyone know a Python regex to parse a 2 digit year to 4 digit e.g 77 to 1977 & 04 to 2004?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I am trying to parse the 2 digit year's structure to 4 digit structure in Python using Pandas. 
Following is my try.

```py
df.Year=re.sub("\s+", "19", df.Year)
```

and countless other attempts at this stage.
Can anybody help me in achieving this solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not 04-> 1904? why it is 2004?

Comment: This requires at least one additional information: which two-digit years belong to 20th and which to 21st century; ie. why you decided that 77 → 1977 rather than 2077?

Comment: Is `df['Year']` of type `str`? Or is it a DateTime column? Please provide a reproducible sample.

Comment: sorry 1920 to 2019

Comment: Try `df['Year'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\b([01][0-9]|20)\b', r'20\1').str.replace(r'\b(2[1-9]|[3-9][0-9])\b', r'19\1')`

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? What is your pd.dataframe looking like?

Comment: list of years as 4 digits with 2 digits thrown in also. need to be able to sort them

Comment: Thanks  Wiktor Stribiżew.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a solution to every problem. Convert the `Year` column to integer and choose a cut-off point, say 49 => 2049, 50 => 1950:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [f'{i:02d}' for i in range(100)]
})

y = df['Year'].astype('int')
df['Year'] = y + np.where(y < 50, 2000, 1900)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Always Sunny and Błotosmętek however, if you're positive the year can only be in the 21st century, I'd try `datetime.strptime()`

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.strptime("19", "%y")
print(time)
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00
```

You can read more about strptime and strftime here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\b\d{2}\b',
  lambda x: '20{}'.format(x.group()) if int(x.group()) < 21 else '19{}'.format(x.group()))
```

With string interpolation:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\b\d{2}\b',
  lambda x: f'20{x.group()}' if int(x.group()) < 21 else f'19{x.group()}')
```

The `\b\d{2}\b` pattern matches two digits not preceded nor followed with word chars (letters, digits or `_`) and the match data object is passed to the lambda, where the logic is the following: if the matched two digits are less than 21, the match value is appended to `20` and returned as the XXIth century date, else, the match value is appended to `19` as the XXth century date.

Pandas test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['Text:21', 'More-78', 'Now:19']})
df['Year'] = df142['Year'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\b\d{2}\b',
    lambda x: '20{}'.format(x.group()) if int(x.group()) < 21 else '19{}'.format(x.group()))
df
# =>
#    0  Text:1921
#    1  More-1978
#    2   Now:2019
```

Comment: OP [has confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290288/anyone-know-a-python-regex-to-parse-a-2-digit-year-to-4-digit-e-g-77-to-1977-0/61291540#comment108426664_61290288) this approach works for them. Besides, it is a much more enhanced solution than [my initial suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290288/anyone-know-a-python-regex-to-parse-a-2-digit-year-to-4-digit-e-g-77-to-1977-0/61291540#comment108426242_61290288), without any complex regex. It may be used even if the input column contains arbitrary text.